# address from latitude and longitud into address

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, gps

Can anyone please help me to get the address text from latitud and longitude, both upload from a database? Also I need to insert the address back into de database with its respective coordinates.

```
<?php    
// Opens a connection to a MySQL server

$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);


$result = mysqli_query($con,'SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY id DESC');


while ($row = @mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

  $latitude=  $row['latitude']. '  ';
  $longitude=  $row['longitude']. '  ';

}

?>
```

Is there a way to get the address and insert it during the while, so it gets the address and sends it right back?
Any help, thanks!

Comment: Use the google maps api, it is too long to explain here. please refer "php google maps" in google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the google maps api, previously they allow anonymous access to their API but now you have to get an API key. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Limits

```
<?php    
// Opens a connection to a MySQL server

$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);


$result = mysqli_query($con,'SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY id DESC');


while ($row = @mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

  $latitude=  $row['latitude']. '  ';
  $longitude=  $row['longitude']. '  ';

  $geolocation = $latitude.','.$longitude;

  // be sure to replace API key
  $request = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.$geolocation.'&sensor=false'.'key=YOUR_API_KEY'; 

  // retrieve data from url, GET REQUEST
  $file_contents = file_get_contents($request);

  // decode json object
  $json_decode = json_decode($file_contents);

  // return the json object of the first record, navigate to the address from here
  var_dump($json_decode);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is called reverse geocoding, translating a location on a map into a human-readable address.

If you are doing this in JavaScript, you will need lat and long (that you mention you already have) and [API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key). With those, you can basically do a GET request using the URL below with the desired lat, long and API key.

```
const lat = 'LAT_COORDS_STRING';
const lng = 'LNG_COORDS_STRING';
const apiKey = 'MY_API_KEY_STRING'

const url = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${lat},${lng}&key=${apiKey}`;
```

The above query will return a JSON (see below) that you can parse and extract the information you need (maybe the field `formatted_address` is what you need).

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "277",
               "short_name" : "277",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Bedford Avenue",
               "short_name" : "Bedford Ave",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Williamsburg",
               "short_name" : "Williamsburg",
               "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Brooklyn",
               "short_name" : "Brooklyn",
               "types" : [ "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Kings",
               "short_name" : "Kings",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "New York",
               "short_name" : "NY",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "11211",
               "short_name" : "11211",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "277 Bedford Avenue, Brooklyn, NY 11211, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 40.714232,
               "lng" : -73.9612889
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.7155809802915,
                  "lng" : -73.9599399197085
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.7128830197085,
                  "lng" : -73.96263788029151
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJd8BlQ2BZwokRAFUEcm_qrcA",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      },

  ... Additional results[] ...
```

For more details take a look at this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding).